# Figuring out if all but one array elements are identical in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know how I would work out if all elements in an array but one have the same value?

I have been trying to work it out for ages but cannot solve it. For example testing an array that has 5 elements to see if it has 4 identical values.

Comment: Use `array_count_values()`. If all but one element is the same, the result will have two elements, and their counts will be 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the idea from Barmar's comment:

```
function allTheSameExceptOne(array $input): bool
{
    $counts = array_count_values($input);
    return count($counts) == 2 && min($counts) == 1;
}
```

- `count($counts) == 2` checks that there are only two distinct elements in the array, and if that is true, then
- `min($counts) == 1` checks that one of those two only appears once

Note that `array_count_values()` can only count string and integer values, so you'll need something more complex than this if you have other types in your array.

Comment: what if the array holds `boolean` values, e.g. `[true, true, false]`?

Comment: @berend good point, I added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange checking, but the function below is doing the check

```
function check(array $array): bool {
    $uniq = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (count($uniq) > 2) {
            return false;
        }
    
        if (!isset($uniq[$value])) {
            $uniq[$value] = 1;
            continue;
        }
    
        foreach ($uniq as $uniqValue => $count) {
            if ($count > 1 && $uniqValue !== $value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        $uniq[$value]++;
    }
    return count($uniq) === 2;
}
```